# Highlight main menu when on specific posts or pages

Tags: php, functions

I am using Genesis and have written a custom function which works fine, but is very ugly and includes a css statement. The object is to highlight a menu link in the main header menu when on certain pages or posts.

This function does not work if I remove the css from the function or if I remove "#header #nav #menu-item-133 a" from the stylesheet. It has to have both, so something is not right even though it does do the job!

Can anyone correct my error(s)? Thanks.

```
function blog_link_genesis() {
    if( is_single() || in_category('investors') || is_page( array(4, 30))) { 
    $current = '#header #nav #menu-item-133 a';  }

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    <?php echo $current; ?> { color: #ff0;}
    </style>
    <?php }
add_action( 'genesis_header' , 'blog_link_genesis'  );
```

Comment: This looks to me like you will be `echo`ing malformed CSS most of the time.

Comment: As I said, it works, but please explain your comment?

Comment: You are printing this line-- `<?php echo $current; ?> { color: #ff0;}`-- every time the function runs, presumably that is on every page load. However, `$current` is only set for some limited pages so what you are actually printing most of the time is `<style type="text/css">{ color: #ff0;}</style>`. Note the missing selector.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that it prints on all pages, and highlights only on the pages I need. But I do not know how to write it correctly that is why I am posting the questions here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can rewrite that part for you but I don't much about Genesis, so I can't say if that will correct your problem or not. I'd guess "not".

Comment: Oh please do, it just has to go in the functions file and I have to add_action to tell Genesis where to put it. Otherwise if it is pure php I can add it directly to a hook. And thank you. I looked high and low for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments above, the OP's code generates malformed CSS. Per request, here is corrected code. It should help solve part of the issue (or prevent other issues) but I doubt it solves all of it.

```
function blog_link_genesis() {
  if( is_single() || in_category('investors') || is_page( array(4, 30))) { 
    $current = '#header #nav #menu-item-133 a'; ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      <?php echo $current; ?> { color: #ff0;}
    </style><?php 
  }
}
add_action( 'genesis_header' , 'blog_link_genesis'  );
```

All you really needed to do was roll the whole block of code into the `if`.

I suspect that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in this question. If you were to explain the problem and the desired result better, I suspect that there is a better way to approach this.

If the menu you mean is this one with "Trials", "Cloud Services", "Bright Eval", etc. then that looks like a standard WordPress menu. If you look at the markup, you will notice a number of useful classes. To add more you want to hook into `nav_menu_css_class` [something like what is done here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100785/21376).

Comment: Thank you, the best way to explain this is to show you the messy test site. http://marazuldelsur.com/wordpress/category/investors/ In the main top menu I need to have Investors highlighted when on the post category of 'investors' but also on the pages which are in the sidebar menu, 'about' and 'cloud-services'. As the category 'investors' is also the main top link I cannot add the other pages as children. Does that explain it any better.

Comment: It is also like getting single posts to highlight the main menu link to a Blog page when they are not children of 'Blog'

Comment: @Lynne : See the edit.

Comment: Sorry, first time poster so not used to formulating my question the right way. Just read XY question and want to clarify that the desired result was already there. I just thought that my code was clumsy and wanted to get the function to pull a selector from the styles.css file, not have to add it into the function as well. I do not need to add extra classes as I am only targeting one main menu link in the blue bar which does not need to be dynamic. And thank you for your help.